# How can I use HTML5 Web Workers with Google Closure Tools?

Tags: javascript, html, google-closure, web-worker, google-closure-library

I need to do some computationally intensive stuff in the background of my app and I've been learning about HTML5 Web Workers. Is there an integrated way to do this with Google Closure Tools? I found [gears.Worker](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_gears_Worker.html) but it isn't clear to me whether this class fits the bill nor how to use it. Thanks!

Comment: I assume you are asking about Closure Library?  Is there something about the native API that seems to be lacking?

Comment: Maybe. The native API seems to want the worker to be in a separate file which didn't seem like it would work too well with the closure library's compiled from. I've found an example that doesn't require another file but it would still be nice to know if this is the best practice for spinning up Web Workers!

Comment: I believe that gears.Worker is meant to work with the discontinued Google Gears project (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_gears) so it unfortunately would seem that it does not have any use with web workers.  Great question, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Web Workers do not need anything special from closure library, except if you want to run without compilation bootstrap/webworkers.js will help. It is used like this

```
/**
 * Closure dependency management, require only main worker script of un-compiled version.
 */
if (typeof COMPILED == 'undefined') {
  CLOSURE_BASE_PATH = '../../../closure-library/closure/goog/';
  importScripts(
      CLOSURE_BASE_PATH + 'bootstrap/webworkers.js',
      CLOSURE_BASE_PATH + 'base.js',
      CLOSURE_BASE_PATH + 'deps.js',
      '/your-script.js');
}
```

`gear` is used before web storage. I guess it is not very good and ugly.

Comment: I don't completely understand! How would I use the sample code you provided to create a web worker? Thanks!

Comment: I will post an example on web worker, which uses database. As I said, web worker is nothing to do with closure compiler. You can put raw or compiled js to web worker, it is same. Closure library does not have anything regarding web worker.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still not sure how this will work together once I compile the Javascript into one source file, but it is working right now!

Comment: You will need two files compiled: your main app logic and the worker. As with source : compile path changes (for example you call goog.require('mynamespace') in source html and then you directly link to the build removing references to source once ready - the same must happen with the worker addres, in development you use the example above, in production you use the compile).